# In a Union-Find algorithm, whether/how to adjust the rank of a node in path compression

Tags: algorithm, tree, union-find

Path compression involves assigning the root as the new parent of every node on the path - this may reduce the rank of the root, and possibly the rank of all nodes on the path. Is there a way to deal with this? And is it necessary to deal with this? Or perhaps is it okay to think of rank as the upper bound of the height of the tree instead of the exact height?

Thanks!

Comment: Only the roots have ranks. Not sure what you're asking, but you can maintain exact ranks quite easily

Comment: I don't understand why people down votes this question. It could be a bit better formulated, but it is a good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can think of the rank as being an upper bound on the height. Its purpose is to limit the lengths of paths to at most logarithmic, by enforcing the invariant that a tree with less than 2^k nodes has height less than k.

Comment: Sure, i think i get it, after reading a bit off of wikipedia and other sources! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about common algorithm of path compression, I think in general it is not possible to decrease the root's rank - because many paths may be connected into this root, not only the path being compressed right now.